# Makefiles: Order only prerequistes and $^

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following in a makefile:

```
.PHONY: preq_test a b c d

a b c d:
    @echo building $@

preq_test : a b | c d
    @echo preq prequisites are: $^;
```

Now, `$^` is supposed to list all prerequisites (besides duplicates) according to the documentation:

```
$^
$+
    The names of all the prerequisites, with spaces between them. For prerequisites
    which are archive members, only the named member is used (see Archives). The value
    of $^ omits duplicate prerequisites, while $+ retains them and preserves their
    order.
```

but the order-only prerequisites do not appear in `$^`:

```
building a
building b
building c
building d
preq prequisites are: a b
```

Can I rely on the current behavior going forward, or is it supposed to work the other way, or should this be considered undefined behavior?

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$^`'s [documented behavior](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#index-_005e-_0028automatic-variable_0029) is to omit order-only prerequisites, so you can rely on it (you [may use](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#index-_007c-_0028automatic-variable_0029) `$|` to get *just* order-only prerequisites, BTW).

Comment: It appears as though $^ is described twice at that url -- once where it says it does not inlcude order-only, and once where it doesn't mention that (guess which one I stumbled across first...).  I'll fire off an email to the document owner.  Thanks,  John

Answer (score 2):

Yes as Anton said `$^` will not list the order-only prerequisites, for printing the dependencies after `|` you have to use `$|`.

Check the below makefile code,

> a b c d:
>
> ```
>       @echo building $@
> ```
>
> preq_test : a b | c d
>
> ```
>       @echo preq prequisites are: $^ $|;
> ```

For more info:

`$^`
The names of all the prerequisites, with spaces between them. For prerequisites which are archive members, only the named member is used (see Archives). A target has only one prerequisite on each other file it depends on, no matter how many times each file is listed as a prerequisite. So if you list a prerequisite more than once for a target, the value of $^ contains just one copy of the name. `This list does not contain any of the order-only prerequisites; for those use` $| `variable.`

`$+`
This is like `$^`, but prerequisites listed more than once are duplicated in the order they were listed in the makefile. This is primarily useful for use in linking commands where it is meaningful to repeat library file names in a particular order.

`$|`
`The names of all the order-only prerequisites, with spaces between them.`